# New Sony Xperia Models - Unable to detect device in adb

Tags: adb, driver, sony-xperia

I tried debugging my app on newer sony xperia models but it's not detected by ADB.

Already tried installing drivers from http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/ but all drivers **failed to install**. I couldn't change the USB Connection to Mass Storage Mode(MSC) because there's no USB Connection Mode setting in Settings > Xperia Connectivity > USB Connectivity like in the picture below

[image: USBConnectivity]

instead of

[image: USBConnectionMode]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't at the moment.

In order to display the Sony Xperia device on adb, you need to select **Mass Storage Mode(MSC)** in **USB Connection Mode** like in the picture below.

[image: USB Connection Mode MSC]

The problem right now, some of the newer models with newer firmware have a bug which is the so called **USB Connection Mode** setting are not displayed in the Settings > Xperia Connectivity > USB Connectivity(refer to the picture below) nor you can find it in other settings.

[image]

Why is it the Mass Storage Mode necessary?
It's because the Xperia default storage mode which is **Media Transfer Protocol(MTP)**. If you take a look of the .inf inside one of the **debugging drivers** available from http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/ , you will see something similar to these lines

```
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_51CB&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_61CB&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_81CB&MI_02
```

and these lines in sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf

```
;Google Nexus One
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01
```

See the differences between %SingleAdbInterface% and %CompositeAdbInterface%?

According to [this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79029/what-is-composite-in-the-android-composite-adb-interface) ,
Android Composite interface is the higher level interface that includes Android ADB (Android Debug Bridge) interface, Android MTP (Media Transfer Protocol), PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol), Mass Storage Protocol etc. depending on what you need to do with connected device and on type of device as well.
That makes the Single ADB Interface which includes only Media Transfer Protocol(MTP) match the word **Single**.

The main problem is that, the **USB Connection Mode** that allows you to switch between **Media Transfer Protocol(MTP)** and **Mass Storage Mode(MSC)** which use the composite adb interface that includes Android Debug Bridge(adb) Interface are not visible in newer firmware for newer models like in the second picture.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm having kind of same problem right now with a tablet Sony Xperia Z4: impossible to detect it with PTP (Mass Storage).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 8/8.1/10, please enable Driver Enforcement Signature to force adb driver installation. After that, you can use universal adb driver installer from adbdriver.com .